# android admob shows only one ad and ad

Tags: android, admob

I am new to using ad-mob and I created a simple app with ad-mob ad in it, and it's working fine except that it only shows only one and the same ad, I tried to close and open the app many times but still shows only one and the same ad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. It could be due to a lack of ad inventory, meaning at that particular time at your geolocation, there are no other ads to serve besides the ad you keep seeing.

Also, check the app's ad settings in the admob console, to make sure "No refresh" is enabled. The ideal refresh rate should be 60seconds.

Comment: thanks for reply,  I selected refresh rate every 30 seconds, because it says its recommended

Comment: Sure! 30 seconds is indeed recommended.